# Switching between last active windows on a Mac

Tags: macos, alt-tab

On Windows and Linux if I hit Alt-Tab it will bring forward the last active window of the application I was using.

If I try to do this on a Mac, Cmd+Tab brings forward *all* the windows of the application.

So if I have a PDF file on each side of the screen, or two Firefox windows, and I switch between the applications, I lose the application I had in the foreground.

Is there some way to disable this behavior and only bring forward the last active window of application instead of all of them?

Comment: My usage is remnant of my Windows/Linux usage: I use Spectacle to tile windows on the left-right side of the screen, and I'm trying to switch between active windows, instead of bringing forward all the windows in an application.

Answer (score -2):

The simple answer is to simply click (with the mouse) on the single window you want. If you have multiple windows opened within a single app, minimizing the "other" windows (click on the red dot in the upper left of the window) until just the desired window is visible will solve your issue. The <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> key combination will show visible tiles from an application.